# "no such module" when Importing pods in swift playground

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift-playground

Using Xcode 7.2.1.

I am following this tutorial to get pods working in playground. i have added the playground into the workspace, and the podfile is linking to the playground.

But importing still does not work - "no such module"

https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/138-using-cocoapods-in-xcode-playgrounds

// import does not work

[image]

```
// Podfile
target 'spaceships' do
end

platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
link_with 'spaceships', 'imports', 'test'
```

https://github.com/mingyeow/ImportToPlaygroundDoesNotWork

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not a direct answer to the issues you get from this tutorial, but there's a new tool to automatically generate Playgrounds with pods that I often use.

It's called *ThisCouldBeUsButYouPlaying* and the source is [on GitHub](https://github.com/neonichu/ThisCouldBeUsButYouPlaying).

**Basically it extends the CocoaPods installer, which is then able to generate Playgrounds.**

Install:

```
$ gem install cocoapods-playgrounds
```

Create a Playground with Alamofire:

```
$ pod playgrounds Alamofire
```

Create a Playground with multiple pods:

```
$ pod playgrounds RxSwift,RxCocoa
```

The new Playground will automatically open.

You will have to **first build** the project, to enable the pods, then the Playground will be available.

[image]

Comment: this.is.amazing. and best.name.ever.

Comment: This project is now archived and not maintained.