# Can't access classes from framework imported in XCode playground

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I can successfully import a framework into my playground, but the classes inside it aren't accessible.

[image: Framework]

[image: Bug]

If I add keyword `public` to Event (and/or its initialiser), the error becomes:

```
'Event' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class
```

What's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Frameworks imported into a playground? Why?

Comment: Take a look at this- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/ImportFramework.html

Comment: @matt, so that I can quickly test my code.

Comment: @Shripada that doesn't help me unfortunately.

Comment: I do it like it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33451726/2227743 And if your framework is in a CocoaPod, there's now this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35818746/2227743

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you build the framework for an appropriate architecture.
In my case I built if for "iPhone 5" (32 bit) and building for a later model (64 bit) solved it.