# How can I use a third party library: SWXMLHash in the playground ?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground, swxmlhash

I'm using SWXMLHash to parse an xml file in my project, It works fine in the project but I would like to make some tests in a playground.

I keep having an error when I want to use the library in the playground:

`Playground execution failed: test.playground:5:8: error: no such module 'SWXMLHash'
import SWXMLHash
       ^`

- I tried to delete the files in the derived data folder.
- I tried to clean and build, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here about a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35818746/2227743

Comment: @EricD. Do you know what to do to avoid this error : `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`

Comment: @EricD. and when I use sudo I get another error : `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/carthage-play`

Comment: Unfortunately you're in the "my Ruby install is broken" pool. First, I highly recommend against using the system's Ruby install - it would force you to install Gems with sudo and will lead to many issues later. You should use something like RBENV or RVM or CHRUBY to install a clean Ruby version. It can be a bit cumbersome but you only have to do it once.

Comment: Tks @EricD. should I uninstall my current ruby and install one of these : RBENV, RVM or CHRUBY to install a clean Ruby version.

Comment: You don't have to uninstall anything. When you will have installed, say, RBENV, you will be able to use RBENV to download and install a new, contained, version of Ruby. RBENV is what downloads, installs and manages the new Ruby install (the idea is to not use the one already installed in the system). The *system Ruby* will not be changed, you will just *add* new Rubies handled by RBENV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make the 3rd party library work in the playground by following the steps provided in the apple docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/ImportFramework.html

I followed the Alternative solution, and now I can use the 3rd party library inside my playground.

Thanks to David Mohundro  the creator of SWXMLHash for the link.

Comment: Link is broken.